# Move a web application to another server but use the same subfolder and domain

Tags: aspnet-compiler

my web application is installed on a Server A like

mywebsite.com/
--> GO to Server A
mywebsite.com/myApp/
--> GO to Server A

and for performance reasons I would like have /myApp/ on an another Server B but using the same domain
mywebsite.com/
--> GO to Server A
mywebsite.com/myApp/
--> GO to Server B

How to do it?

I use MS .net 4, IIS 7 on MS Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a load balancer in front of servers A and B so that you could direct traffic appropriately?  Do you have a firewall that may be able to support a rule to route traffice with that "/myApp" to go to B?  Those would be my suggestions for ways to do it without changing the servers.  However, if you did have to change the server, I would consider having an ISAPI filter that moves the requests to the other machine, but this is likely done better by setting up different domain names so that you have a mywebsite.com and a myapp.website.com so that each can resolve to a different server.  If you do that, then server A just has to redirect the request to the other server for a simpler solution.  Anyway, that is a few different ways to do it that I can see.

---

The trade-offs in firewall vs load balancer are really probably quite minuscule as many big sites have load balancers and firewalls, though I'd question the cost difference in having a load balancer versus changing firewall settings.  I'd also investigate how feasible each option is for your situation.

Comment: Hi, I cannot use another sub domains but must stay on the same first level domain and is sub folder, what is performance best... load balance or firewall generally?